# Limit the number of newline of dynamic textarea in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to limit the number of newline that can be enter in a dynamic textarea, but the codes I made is not working. I need to set atleast 4 newlines that the user can make. Also I set the maxlength to 40 characters. 

 
here is my codes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("[name='memo[]']").each(function(){
         $(this).keydown(function() {

                newLines = $(this).val().split("\n").length;
                $(this).text(newLines);

                if(e.keyCode == 13 && newLines >= 4) {
                    alert("Exceed");
                    return false;
                }


            });
        });
  });
```

Comment: you can also try textarea's rows attribute
`<textarea rows='4'>`

Comment: @paulitto `rows` just defined height of textarea.

Comment: @Bob khin indeed, you are right

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[name='memo[]']").each(function() {
        var textarea = $(this);
        textarea.attr('maxlength', 40);

        textarea.keydown(function(e) {

            var newLines = textarea.val().split(/\r*\n/).length;

            if (e.keyCode === 13 && newLines >= 4) {        
                e.preventDefault();
            }    
        });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**:
Dont alert and the code works fine. Demo link is: http://jsfiddle.net/bobkhin/nJWk2/

Comment: I think the reason it did not work is due to the textareas are inside a TD.

Comment: Hi I still can't make it work. I dont know why. I think the problem is that the textarea is inside the TD, :(

Comment: Can you provide me the log?

Answer (score 0):

get the lines in text area with the below example code and try...

```
 String.prototype.lines = function() { return this.split(/\r*\n/); }
 String.prototype.lineCount = function() { return this.lines().length; }
```